# How to present dynamic string collection on android application

Tags: android

In my application - i need to present ( in the UI ) some dynamic string collection.

This collection need to have ability to add/remove some string that comes from other component.

The string collection exist on some singleton class.

What is the easy way to show this dynamic collection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your string in a linked list, then you create a listview. You create a base adapter witch takes as arguments your string list and pass the adapter to the list view;

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourStringValues)
listView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

your string items will be showed to the user, then you may want to implement listview's on touch listener in order to show a menu which can be used to delete an element

Comment: look ... the trick with the listView && adapter is something that i know. But i want to do it without any of those. string collection is something that need to be simple to show. There is no other way ?

Comment: This is the easiest way, in this case you don't have to extend any class, just create an adapter object as I showed you above and pass it to a listview's object. Other methods that comes to my mind is to adding views in Java but in my opinion it's more complicated

Comment: but if the string collection change - how i see the changes ( add/remove ) on the adapter ?

Comment: when collection changes you need to call     
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: or if you prefer: `((ArrayAdapter) mMyListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` `notifyDataSetChanged()` will tell to the listView that the collection is changed and the listView should redraw itself.                                                        If you want you can also store your string array in xml and create an array of strings in java at run time with ` yourStringValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);` where testArray is <array name="testArray">  
    <item>first</item>  
    <item>second</item>  
     </array>

Answer (score 1):

1. Store Dynamic collection in Shared preference in json format using
   GSON libray.
2. Retrive and parse usong GSON libray to display it anywhere
3. Implement Interface or local bradcast where ever is
   added/updated/removed and updated value and restore it in shared
   preference